# Mmap returns 0 on MacOS X 10.8.2 in assembler

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64

I'm just doing some assembly for fun on MacOS X and at the moment am just trying to map a file into memory using the mmap system call, however i'm a bit puzzled at the moment. Here's the code snippet:

```
movq $0x20000c5, %rax               //mmap syscall
xorq %rsi,%rsi                      //
movq %rcx,%rdi                      //size of the file is in rcx
movq $0x1,%rdx                      //read only
movq $0x1,%r10                      //shared
movq finput(%rip),%r8               //file descriptor
xorq %r9,%r9                        //no offset
syscall
```

This does not produce an error in the sense that the carry-flag is set however it returns 0 in rax where I thought it should actually return a pointer to the memory it has mapped the file to. I've ofcourse tried checking the obvious things and there is nothing wrong with the filesize or the file descriptor. I bet there's something obvious I'm missing here but I just can't see it at the moment. Would be most thankful for any help.

Comment: Can you try to do the same using C language then look at the assembly code in debugger ?

Comment: I followed your advice and realized that i had made a mistake with the order of the arguments. RSI should have been RDI and vice versa. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have added an answer with the correction.

Answer (score 0):

(The answer is in a comment, so I report it here)

The RSI and RDI arguments are not in the right order. The correct code is:

```
movq $0x20000c5, %rax               //mmap syscall
xorq %rdi,%rdi                      //
movq %rcx,%rsi                      //size of the file is in rcx
movq $0x1,%rdx                      //read only
movq $0x1,%rcx                      //shared
movq finput(%rip),%r8               //file descriptor
xorq %r9,%r9                        //no offset
syscall
```